# Last pid process linux

Tags: linux, pid

I'm trying to get the last pid of a process (for example sleep). I do this:

```
# sleep 10 &
[1] 14115
```

But when I use this command to get the last pid:

```
# ps aux --sort +start_time | tail -n 4 | awk 'NR==1{print $2 " " $11}'
14125 sleep
```

The pid is not the same, i don't understand what I'm doing wrong, because if I do the same but without the last part of the command, I get the same pid:

```
# sleep 10 &
[1] 15853

# ps aux --sort +start_time | tail -n 4
root     15853  0.0  0.1   3364   520 pts/2    S    16:45   0:00 sleep 10
www-data 15871  0.0  0.0   1864   452 ?        S    16:45   0:00 sleep 1
root     15872  0.0  0.2   4344  1168 pts/2    R+   16:45   0:00 ps aux --sort +start_time
root     15873  0.0  0.1   3756   676 pts/2    S+   16:45   0:00 tail -n 4
```

Thanks in advance

**[Solved]**

```
# ps aux --sort +start_time | tail -n 5 | awk 'NR==1{print $2 " " $11}'
```

another solution for a concrete process

```
# pgrep -n 'name_of_the_process'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `awk` process is started, and occupies another line in the output. Try `tail -n 5`, but it's not reliable, as another process could be started in between, anyway. See `psgrep`.

Comment: I got it with tail -n5, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the pid of the last process with:
echo $!